# Class P is closed under concatenation

Tags: complexity-theory, closure-properties, polynomial-time

Proving that Class P is closed under concatenation.

The answer is given below:

[image]

But I do not know why stage 2 is repeated at most O(n), could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  How many times do you think it could be repeated?  How many times could the loop iterate?

Comment: the number of times equal to the length of w >>> right? @D.W.

Comment: Yes. Since n denotes the length of the input, n = length(w). As you noted, step 2 repeats O(length(w)) = O(n) times.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Bah, that proof sketch is unnecessarily imprecise. You may want to look for a better resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $n = |w|$ the length of $w$, step 2 is repeated exactly $n+1$ times.

But they assume implicitly that $n$ is the length of the input (which is canonical in complexity theory), i.e. $|\langle w \rangle|$ with an unspecified encoding $\langle.\rangle$ of strings.
(Why they insist to introduce that encoding here, I don't know.)

The $O$ (which should be a $\Theta$) comes from that encoding as well. While there are exactly $|w| + 1$ ways to cut $w$ in two parts, we don't know the exact figure in terms of $|\langle w \rangle|$.

They forget to mention their assumption that that encoding is reasonable in a certain way, i.e. $|\langle w \rangle| \in \Theta(|w|)$ for all $w$.

Comment: I suspect that $\langle w \rangle = w$, i.e., there is no encoding involved. Also, the big $O$ is used as an *upper bound*, so there's no harm in using $O(n)$ rather than $\Theta(n)$.